# Stripe: How to transfer amount to customer

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe SDK with PHP Laravel 5.1. I am receiving payment from registered user of certain type. Upon certain steps I'd like to transfer a certain amount of their payment to other users who already added their `cards` in Stripe. How can I do that?

Right now I m only asking his Credit Card Info and storing in `Card` object. Should I need to ask his bank account information as well?

Comment: You cannot transfer funds to a customer's card. You can use Stripe Connect, but that use case is more that a a user is paying another user (like a vendor charging a customer), and is a bit more nuanced than just arbitrarily transferring funds.

Comment: @MatthewArkin Ok, is there anyway to let customer know to have payment on Stripe and he gets link of it?

Comment: you would need to use Stripe connect and create the charge in the user's account

Comment: @MatthewArkin any example in this regard? Also, you said `Charge`, should it not be `Transfer` object?

Comment: I'd suggest reading through stripe.com/docs/connect and stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees You should never be creating a transfer object to send funds to another person's account.